Replacement for Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate doesn't work as expected
void startResendTimer(){
    resendOtpTextView.setEnabled(false);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            timeoutSeconds--;
            resendOtpTextView.setText("Resend OTP in "+timeoutSeconds +" seconds");
            if(timeoutSeconds<=0){
                timeoutSeconds =60L;
                timer.cancel();
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    resendOtpTextView.setEnabled(true);
                });
            }
        }
    },0,1000);
}

When I use scheduleAtFixedRate, that entire code block is crossed out. When I use schedule, the event I want does not happen. Why?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

1000 milliseconds (1 second) is quite a very short time. Make sure that your block of code is always executable within that 1 second.
schedule should execute the code block only once. So if the block execution fails, there's no second chance of execution.
